# Showing partial class properties in Entity Framework designer

Tags: entity-framework

Does anyone know if there is a way to add a property to a my partial class that will show in the Entity Framework designer so I can use it in my mapping to a stored procedure? I can modify the edmx, but would prefer to avoid it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the Entity Framework (and the Designer) are completely unaware of your partial class properties. If you intend to use a property in a Stored Procedure mapping etc, you will need to add the property into the model.

So yes you will have to modify the EDMX.

Alex James

(Program Manager Entity Framework Team)

Comment: Thanks Alex. I'll have to go that way.